# SQL query on MySQL taking three second longer with no changes to the database or to the SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

I have been asked to diagnose why a query looking something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM users 
WHERE first_digit BETWEEN 500 AND 1500 
  AND second_digit BETWEEN 5000 AND 45000;
```

went from taking around 0.3 seconds to execute suddenly is taking over 3 seconds. The system is MySQL running on Ubuntu.

The table is not sorted and contains about 1.5M rows. After I added a composite index I got the execution time down to about 0.2 seconds again, however this does not explain the root cause why all of a sudden the execution time increased exponentially.

How can I begin to investigate the cause of this?

Comment: First step, review the explain plan.

Comment: The execution plan has stayed the same i know for a fact. The problem must be external to MySql.

Comment: Network issue..

Comment: If you remove your new index, does the query get to 3 sec again?

Comment: Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your SQL query has not changed, and I interpret your description as the data set has not changed/grown - I suggest you take a look at the following areas, in order:

1) Have your removed the index and run your SQL query again?

2) Other access to the database. Are other applications or users running heavy queries on the same database? Larger data transfers, in particular to and from the database server in question.

Answer (score 0):

A factor of 10 slowdown?  A likely cause is going from entirely cached to not cached.

Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. `EXPLAIN SELECT`, RAM size, and the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  And how big (GB) is the table?

Also, did someone happen to do a dump or `ALTER TABLE` or `OPTIMIZE TABLE` just before the slowdown.

The above info will either show what caused caching to fail, or show the need for more RAM.

`INDEX(first_digit, second_digit)` (in either order) will be "covering" for that query; this will be faster than without any index.